# Is an exception catch functionally the same as promise errorCallback?

Tags: javascript, promise, angular-promise

I've been using javascript promsises thoughout my angular application but I am tired of repeating the same errorCallback for every promise. I am considering simply wrapping a promise in a try/catch block and having the catch block deal with any promise failures.

Which leads me to asking the question - are the error callbacks redundant if they are in a try/catch block? Will javascript 'catch' the error failure?

Edit: Adding code to reflect how I plan to do this:

```
try {
  $http.post().success(callback); 
}(catch)
{
}
```

The same as:

```
$http.post().succes(callback()).error(callback)
```

Comment: Please show specific code you are asking about.  Exceptions are not the same as promise failures and exceptions don't natively propagate from asynchronous callbacks.  This can only be answered when you ask about specific code.

Comment: You should also mention which promise library you are using because different libraries have different features for handling exceptions within a promise handler.

Comment: Added my code. Using angulars $http which is based off angulars $q. Have yet to decide which one I should use

Comment: Don't you really mean `$http.post().success(callback);` without the parens after `callback`?

Comment: It's actually possible to write code like this if you're willing to use bleeding edge browser features like generators and transpile for older browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't. The reason is that what you are actually doing is queuing your callback function to be invoked when the request gets a successful, *asynchronous* response. By that time, the execution will have moved past your `try/catch` block, and you will get an unhandled error.

Another way to look at it is that synchronous, thrown errors *immediately* propagate up the call tree to the nearest catch block whereas asynchronous error results will *only* be handlable via the deferred object.

If you wish to invoke the same error handler for multiple promise-based asynchronous operations, you have multiple ways of going about it. The most obvious is injecting `$q` to your controller and doing something like this:

```
var deferred1 = $http.get(...);
var deferred2 = someOtherPromiseBasedMethod(...);

$q.all([deferred1, deferred2, ..., deferredN])
    .then(null, function (rejection) {
        // first failed deferred will provide the rejection value here
    });
```

Another approach is to create a wrapper function:

```
function handleError(deferred) {
    return deferred.then(null, commonErrorHandler);
}

handleError($http.get(...)).then(function (result) {
    // Handle the success case here
}
```

That's still a bit repetitive, but less so, while being more of a declarative approach.